# Button position isn't changing despite adding style to it

Tags: css, asp.net, bootstrap-4

I am trying to move the button to the right, and it's on a modal form if that somehow makes a difference, but it's not budging no matter what I do. I cannot create a separate CSS class for the code, just use the universal one.

Here's the code:

```
<asp:Panel ID="PnlUpdateSubjectPin" runat="server" CssClass="row" Visible="false">
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel140" runat="server" CssClass="col-6">
        <asp:Button ID="BtnGenNewPin" runat="server" Text="Generate Pin" CssClass="btn-success margin-left: 50px" />
```

Comment: You might want to do a tutorial about css and styles and the use of classes.

Comment: Hello. Yeah, I have been, but I thought I was able to write an inline expression for this? The CSS class being used is used in multiple areas, so I cant change it directly.

Thanks.

Comment: No, it's either `class="btn-success"` or `style="margin-left: 50px"`

Comment: Okay - thank you for that. There must be something somewhere written in this project that is positioning the other Elements, I'll just have to find it. I'm not sure why this was written this way. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can't put the style elements in to the "class" you specify for that button.

Use a Style for things you want to add - the CssClass does NOT allow css, but ONLY allows you to specify existing css class(s) you want to use.

So, try this:

```
<asp:Button ID="BtnGenNewPin" runat="server" 
   Text="Generate Pin" CssClass="btn-success" 
   Style="margin-left:25px" />
```

the above should work just fine. So, don't try to put/shove css into the CssClass setting. You are free to use Style= in above, and it will be respected, and in fact should not mess nor bother with the existing class(s) you specified in the CssClass settings.

CssClass simple does not allow you to add or put css into that setting - only class(s) can be used by that setting.

Use Style  -- you should be just fine.